# How to pass a class as a parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I have following method, which is read JSON from the directory and de-serialize the JSON into C# class object.

```
public static JObject readJson(string fileName)
{
    string JSON = "";
    List<string> keyList = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        JSON = r.ReadToEnd();
    }
    JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(JSON);
    var name = parsed["2"];
    Numbers deserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Numbers>(name.ToString());
    return parsed;
}
```

Here you can see, I'm used class called `Numbers`. I'm passing separate JSON file's name to the above method, based on that I also need to pass Class to convert JSON into C# object. How can I pass class to the above method as a generic? then I think I can modify this line,

```
var deserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnyClass>(name.ToString());
```

is it possible to do?

Comment: Do I get this right, that you actually want to return `deserializedClass` (strongly typed) ?

Comment: ^^ if so: `public static TResult ReadJson<TResult>(string fileName)` and use it inside as `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(name.ToString());`

Comment: Hmm... how does you json look like? Why do you need to parse it prior the deserialize?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public static JObject readJson<T>(string fileName)
    {
        string JSON = "";
        List<string> keyList = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            JSON = r.ReadToEnd();
        }
        JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(JSON);
        var name = parsed["2"];
        Numbers deserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(name.ToString());
        return parsed;
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/ 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics

Comment: Now, this fails if T is not assignable to `Numbers`...

Comment: readJson<Numbers>( )

Comment: It's generic. `Numbers deserializedClass = <Something incompatible with Numbers>;` will fail.

Comment: ``var deserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(name.ToString());`` should avoid the Exception, but if you return ``parsed``, what would you need the deserialized Object for?

Comment: I had given my answer at the same time as nt_qwark, which returns the actual class you specify using the generic on the method instead of returning the JObject.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses Generics and will take the Type you specify and return the object of that type.

```
public static T readJson<T>(string fileName)
{
    var JSON = string.Empty;
    using (var r = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        JSON = r.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var parsed = JObject.Parse(JSON);
    var name = parsed["2"];
    var deserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(name.ToString());
    return deserializedClass;
}
```

Usage:

`var resultObject = readJson<Number>(fileName);`

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics

Comment: Didn't see that `nt_qwark` answered until after I submitted mine, was testing out my solution before posting haha